# ajax is working in jquerymobile but not working in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquerymobile and wrapping it with phonegap. 
I'm using AJAX to retrieve data from server, and it works perfectly on my browser, but when i tried to do it using phonegap application, the ajax call doesn't seems to work.
In the AJAX call I'm calling to a local php file that retrieve the data from the server with the code line "file_get_contents". 
my phonegap version is 2.0.0, and i also tried to add an access tag in the res\config.xml file with the server url, and i allow internet connection in the application.

Thank you

This is the ajax code I'm using, and when i'm giving the direct url to the server the ajax call fails, and when i give a url to a local php file(not in the server), that retrieve the data from the server, the ajax call success.

$.ajax({
        url      :  url + query,
        dataType : 'html',
        success  : function (response) {

```
        $.mobile.loading('hide');

        $('body').append(response);

        $.mobile.changePage('#page3');
    },
    error    : function () {           
        alert('loading error') ;
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, when you say a "local php file", are you referring to one on a local server, or one in the same file directory?  PhoneGap will not process PHP files in the directory structure within a PhoneGap application.  The PHP file must reside on a web server that can handle PHP.

Comment: my php file is in the directory structure within my phonegap application.and it has only the code line that retrieve the data directly from the server("file_get_contents").i tried to give the url of the server in the ajax call, but it didn't worked the only way it worked is if i call a local php file that retrieve the data from the server.how can i check if phonegap support php, or is their a package that i should download that it will support php?

Comment: PhoneGap does not support PHP. PhoneGap is based on the system web view from the mobile operating system. It can render HTML, JS & CSS, but PHP is a server-side language. PhoneGap applications do not support PHP processing either in the emulator, or on a device. You will need to implement a different solution.  If the data you want to get is on a server, you should be able to just make an ajax request to that server.  When you are accessing a relative file in a phonegap app (relative to the directory structure), you are requesting a file off of the device's physical storage, not from a server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answers the are very useful. so if i can't use php, anyone know why i can't success to performe an ajax call directly to the sever and only throw a php file.i added the code i use, and explanation to my first posting.

Comment: Do you have an error message or HTTP status code?  You can capture them in the result handler.  See docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference It is probably an issue that the URL is incorrect, or the server is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your server is whitelisted (even if it is local).  See details here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

You can whitelist all urls just by adding "*".   Also, make sure you reference the file from an absolute URL, not a relative URL.

Comment: i did that i already read that post, and i add an access tag(in res/config.xml) with the server url, and it still didn"t worked.